# Espresso or UIAutomation solution to click either the parent or next node

Tags: android-espresso, android-uiautomator

I have a problem statement after scrolling down in Android app where I wanted to click on an element but this element is not clickable. Below you see the UIAutomator page structure.

[![UIAnimator page structure][1]][1]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PhuV.png)

I have an element of TEXTVIEW with the text "TRENDING", but this element is not clickable. Hence I require parent which is VIEWGROUP having content-desc as "image_image_container" as shown in the image and I need it to be identified and clicked on "image_image_container".
Is there a way to do that either in UIAutomator or Espresso or get the coordinates of the text "TRENDING" Text on the app?
Basically my scenario is I'm doing automation on the app. When I launch the app and navigate to this page on app. I basically want to traverse through this viewgroup "view_image_container" and get all children and this children list I'm expecting the "TRENDING" text available in textview and then traverse through the same viewgroup "view_image_container" and get viewgroup ID "touchable_info" and perform click on this specific "touchable_info". Since this page has other nested viewgroup items as well. For details you can see my image attached.

Scenario is something like this.
Take "view_image_container" as parent viewgroup ----> identify child of Textview having text "TRENDING" ----> identify Child with I'd "touchable_info" under same "view_image_container" -----> perform click on this child "touchable_info" viewgroup

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hamcrest's `allOf` function to chain together multiple Matchers. I'm not sure of which elements you are referencing in your image, but it would be something like...

```kotlin
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.image_image_container), withChild(withId(R.id.textview_element))).perform(click())
```

You can use multiple `allOf`s in your matcher.

Comment: Agoff, Basically my scenario is I'm doing automation on the app. When I launch the app and navigate to this page on app. I basically want to traverse through this viewgroup "view_image_container" and get all children and this children list I'm expecting the "TRENDING" text available in textview and then traverse through the same viewgroup "view_image_container" and get viewgroup ID "touchable_info" and perform click on this specific "touchable_info". Since this page has other nested viewgroup items as well. For details you can see my image attached.

Comment: Scenario is something like this

Comment: You can refer this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnjNi.png                               Scenario is something like this.
Take "view_image_container" as parent viewgroup ----> identify child of Textview having text "TRENDING" ----> identify Child with I'd "touchable_info" under same "view_image_container" -----> perform click on this child "touchable_info" viewgroup [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnjNi.png

Comment: onView(allOf(withContentdescrpition(view_image_container), withChild(withText("TRENDING")), withChild(withContentdescrpition(touchable_info))).perform(click()) ---> will this work for me?

Comment: Not quite. In your given, you'd try to click on the `view_image_container` element. I'd try something like `onView(allOf(withContentDescription(touchable_info), isDescendantOfA(allOf(withContentDescription(view_image_container), withChild(withText("TRENDING"))))))`.  My example finds the `touchable_info` that has a parent with content description `view_image_container` and that parent has a child element with text "TRENDING".

Comment: You might need to play around a little bit to get the exact match, but let me know if this does or doesn't work and I can update my answer. You need to make sure that you uniquely reference whatever element you want to interact with. In your example, you reference the `view_image_container` that has a child with text and a child with content description.

Comment: Tried this 
onView(allOf(withContentDescription("touchable_info"), isDescendantOfA(allOf(withContentDescription("view_image_container"), withChild(withText("TRENDING")))))).perform(click());
Got error 
androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with content description text: is "touchable_info" and is descendant of a: (with content description text: is "view_image_container" and has child: with text: is " TRENDING "))

Comment: ViewInteraction onViewPLPx =  onView(allOf(withContentDescription("touchable_info"),
                    isDescendantOfA(allOf(withContentDescription("image_tag"),
                            withChild(withText(" NEW "))))));
This is kind of clicking the NEW text Textview, but this non clickable link.

Comment: Tried this as well  ViewInteraction onViewPLP0 =onView(allOf(withText(" NEW "),
                    isDescendantOfA(withContentDescription("image_tag")),
                    isDescendantOfA(withContentDescription("touchable_image_container"))));
            onViewPLP0.perform(click());   
but onview i'm not getting this clicked as this element "touchable_image_container" not available, is this problem due to scrollview? so i use onData()?

Comment: Added New image see the origin link please